# why tell me I can create new tags after I have input the right "I'm Human" identify

Tags: feature-request, new-tags-page

I am newbie here.
When I input the tags,there is no prompt about I can't create new tags.
And When I finally recognize the "I'm human" picture after several refresh,you turn back to the edit page to tell me that I have no right to create new tags.
Quite frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the tags exist before you try to post.

[image]